# EF Core 5 Store and Query Array of Strings

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

What would be the best option in EF Core 5 to store and query an array of strings? I am specifically thinking of tags associated with a document and I would like to retrieve all documents that contain one tag.

I tried mapping a `string []` property with the help of a value converter, something like:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Document>()
    .Property(x => x.Tags)
    .HasConversion(v => string.Join(',', v), v => v.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

The mapping works fine, the property is persisted ok, however if I try to query on this property, with a simple operator such as `Contains`, it fails with an exception:

```
var results = ctx.Documents.Where(doc => doc.Tags.Contains("foo")).ToList();
```

What other options I have, besides mapping each tag as an entry on a different table? I could go with that, but I would like to avoid it if possible, for the extra burden.

Comment: Why is it an extra burden? Think about how you would do this without Entity Framework, you would definitely keep the tags in their own table.

Comment: No, I wouldn't... In NHibernate, I surely wouldn't, at least.

Comment: I advice to keep them in json column. Also you can query them. This is little old but still working. https://github.com/iozcelik/EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.JsonExtention/blob/master/test/EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.JsonExtention.Test/JsonQueryTest.cs#L14